# How to set icon of JFrame in eclipse

Tags: java, swing

I have tried everything on the web for setting icon of jframe in eclipse but still I'm unable to set icon for jframe in eclipse. Also I have three different ways of doing this. Explain the difference between these ways and tell me method  of setting an icon for jframe in eclipse not netbeans.

EDIT:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class MainClass {
static JFrame frame= new JFrame();
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    frame.setTitle("GUI Practice");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBounds(100,100,400,300);   
//Thanks....This works
    try {


            frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(MainClass.class.getResource("icon.gif")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //But why this does not works 
            //Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("/icon.gif");
            //frame.setIconImage(img);  
    }
}
```

Comment: (1-) `I have three different ways of doing this. Explain the difference between these ways` - we are not mind readers. We have no idea what the "3 different ways" are that you are talking about. Post your code showing what you have tried. The code should be posted in the form of a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: But before you do as suggested by @camickr. be sure to read the Java Docs for any method involved in the 3 ways. SO is no substitute for Reading The Fine Manual..

Comment: I have updated my question with my code. Can you answer that whats in the comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do it like this:

```
try {
    frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note:** Put the image icon in the `classpath`

Comment: Thanks you saved me but can you explain your code and i have to change getClass by my class name because it gives me a static reference to a nonstatic function. Thanks

Comment: @SAIFI369 It is because you are doing thing in main method that is static. So in this point you can use classname.this.getRe… as you done in your code (after edit).

Comment: Ok i got that but can you explain your code so that I can understand what is actually happening??? And do u know why the other method does not work???

Comment: This method works because it get used the getResource() method, which looking for resource in the classpath, the classpath is the path that is directed to the compiled classes path of the source code (relative path to the resources). If you put any file inside the src folder, then it will be compiled to the classpath with compiler. The getdefaulttoolkit is also working, but it needs an absolute path to the file, which not included in the project, in the feature if you changed the location of the image then it will not work, which is not good to use this method. Hope I cleared it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way (image refference remains declared if you need it later in your program, also your file could be located anywhere in your storage, independent of the program):

```
Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("path/to/img.png");
frame.setIconImage(img);
```

*Next time you post a question please be more explicit about your current knowledge compared to what you need. Learn about SSCCE.*

Good luck!

Comment: You just have to provide the correct location of the icon. Try "/src/img.png" or "src/img.png" or "/img.png" or "img.png". If these all won't work simply copy-paste the full location "C:/Code/eclipse/eclipse-neon/workspace/project/src/img.png" or something like that.

Comment: I mean what does toolkit is or getdefaulttoolkit is??

Comment: Read about it here: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/api/java.awt.Toolkit.html and here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html